# ExpressJS/Mongoose Set variable to MongoDB result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a NodeJS app using Express and Mongoose. I am trying to write a POST route so that when a POST request to the URL is made (currently /api/v1/forms/:formId) then it will set the variable to the recipient`value from the MongoDB database. The :formID will match the _id in MongoDB.

So far I have:

```
app.post("/api/v1/forms/:formId", async (req, res) => {
    //TODO: Create Mailer and email templates before finalising route.
    const { _name, _email, _message } = req.body;

    const form = Form({
      name = req.body._name,
      email = req.body._email,
      message = req.body._message,
      recipient = Form.findById(req.params.form_id, function(err, form) {
        if (err)
          res.send(err);

      })
    });


    const mailer = new Mailer(form, contactFormTemplate(form));
    try {
      await mailer.send();
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(422).send(err);
    }
  });
```

I know this is not correct for the `recipient` field but this is what I could think of off the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

Following what you did, you can do this:

```
app.post("/api/v1/forms/:formId", async (req, res) => {
    //TODO: Create Mailer and email templates before finalising route.
    const { _name, _email, _message } = req.body;

    let recipient;
    try{
      recipient = await Form.findById(req.params.form_id).exec();
    } catch(err){
      res.status(422).send(err);
    }

    const form = Form({
      name: req.body._name,
      email: req.body._email,
      message: req.body._message,
      recipient: recipient
    });


    const mailer = new Mailer(form, contactFormTemplate(form));
    try {
      await mailer.send();
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(422).send(err);
    }
});
```

The `.exec()` on mongoose return a promise, so it's possible to use async/await syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the problem, here is what I could think of,

```
Form.findById(req.params.form_id, function(err, form) {
        if (err){
          res.send(err);
        }else{
          recipient = form.recipientValue;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
app.post("/api/v1/forms/:formId", async (req, res) => {
    const { _name, _email, _message } = req.body;

    let form;        

    try {
        form = await Form.findById(req.params.formId).select('recipient').exec();
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return;
    }

    const nuForm = Form({
        name = req.body._name,
        email = req.body._email,
        message = req.body._message,
        recipient = form.recipient
    });

    try {
        await new Mailer(nuForm, contactFromTemplate(nuForm)).send();
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(422).send(err);
    }
}
```